# Laravel Database Migration Error PDO\Exception::new(Object(PDOException)) & SQLSTATE[42P07]

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, migration

Hello im begginer at laravel I was given a repo with database, and then when i want run new migration -php artisan migrate it gives an exception like this picture, anyone know how to solve this? thx before

laravel\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception.php:18
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception::("SQLSTATE[42P07]: Duplicate table: 7 ERROR:  relation "personal_access_tokens" already exists")

laravel\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:119
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception::new(Object(PDOException))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DI45.png)

Comment: try using `php artisan migrate:fresh --force`

Comment: thxx mister, this is worked! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow those steps:

```
1.Run git clone <project-name-from-github>
2.Run composer install
3.Run cp .env.example .env
4.Run php artisan key:generate
5.Run php artisan migrate or php artisan migrate:fresh --force
6.Run php artisan serve
```

Comment: You're welcoming, happy coding ^^